# Is there a way to launch an application on a particular display?

Tags: macos, terminal, display, script

I'm considering writing a script that would open a bunch of apps. For example, it would open Slack on my secondary display, Chrome on a primary and Firefox on a third one. Right now, I can open a file from a terminal using `open <appname>` command but this does not provide an interface to choose the preferred display.

Is there a way to do that programmatically?

I was checking [NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace) but couldn't find the option to specify a display either.

Comment: This might help https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161701/how-can-i-force-an-application-to-be-launched-to-the-2nd-monitor#161720

Comment: This does not help much - I want to have multiple windows of a single app (e.g. web browser) among different monitors. And to be able to change my decision where the app starts without a need to click on it (yikes) and change some display settings.