# How to Force an Application to Open in a Specific Monitor

Tags: macbook-pro, display, spaces, mission-control

How can I assign an application to, by default, open in a specific monitor?

I have an additional monitor that is connected via HDMI to my Macbook, which allows me to use the two screens as if they were one. But whenever I open an application, it sometimes opens on the Macbook monitor; other times it opens on the other monitor, which can be annoying and very inconvenient. I would have the Dock in my Macbook screen, open an application from that Dock, and then all of a sudden the application launches in the other monitor, forcing me to move my cursor all the way to the other monitor just to access it.

I have read the article [How can I force an application to be launched to the 2nd monitor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161701/how-can-i-force-an-application-to-be-launched-to-the-2nd-monitor#:%7E:text=Consider%20the%20simpler%20solutions%20first%3A%201%20First%20decide,management%20systems%2C%20some%20free%20and%20some%20paid.%20) previously to help solve this issue, but the Dock does not seem to allow me to assign an application to either monitor despite having both monitors set as separate spaces in mission control.

[image: After trying to enable treating both displays as separate spaces.]

I have also tried to quit the application in the Macbook display and reopen it, but it still opens on the other monitor.

By the way, the version I am using is Sonoma 14.2.1.