Fix Microsoft Outlook Main Window Position
On a multiple display system, Microsoft Outlook always opens on the currently active display.
The previous position of Outlook is ignored.
The NSWindow Frame MainWindow value in the plist always gets overwritten to the new window position.
How do I keep this value fixed? Or in more general terms, how can I make Outlook remember its previous location and open the Window at that exact location?

Have you tried assigning Outlook to a specific space? To do so, move the Outlook window to the desired display, right-clicki (or Control-click) the Outlook icon in the Dock,  choose Options and select Desktop on Display  (see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161701/how-can-i-force-an-application-to-be-launched-to-the-2nd-monitor and https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-in-multiple-spaces-mh14112/mac for details). Please report back if this solves your problem, I can then add an answer.

@jaume. Thanks. I didn't have Desktop on Display in Options. I did however solve the problem and have posted my solution.

The solution to the problem was making a change to the Mission Control settings.
Go to System Settings -> Desktop & Dock and find Mission Control at the bottom. Toggle off Displays have separate Spaces.
When toggling off, you are required to logout once and log back in.

